# svn to git conversion no refs in common

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to convert an svn repository to git following the instructions at http://www.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git.  I've done this once before following the same instructions, and it worked, but this time at step 4 in the instructions "git push bare" I get the following error.

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to '/Users/[ME]/new-bare.git'
```

Anyway to get past this error? or is there a better way to convert from svn to git?

Comment: The guide is convoluted at points... I'd never have touched the HEAD of the bare like that. Anyway: try `git push bare master`

Comment: @fge +1 it resolved my same error. Can you please suggest why adding master to bare push resolved this error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also tried to follow the guide, it's complex and didn't work for me.
I've no idea why, what I did is simple:
1. git svn clone YOUR_SVN_REPOSITORY
2. Manually fix the author in commit history([How do I change the author of a commit in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git)).