# SVN to GIT migration giving error as No refs in common

Tags: git, svn, version-control, gitlab, git-svn

I am trying to migrate my projects from svn to git, based on steps given in this url: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/perform-migration-from-svn-to-git?view=vsts#push-repository-to-a-bare-git-repository

But while pushing repository to bare git repository, I am getting below error:

```
C:\Git_Workspace\git_Repo>git push bare
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to '../new_bare_repo.git'
```

I found one similar question here [svn to git conversion no refs in common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730797/svn-to-git-conversion-no-refs-in-common) solution there is not helping but one comment suggested to add master like:

```
git push bare master
```

But it is not pushing my projects in bare repo just creating master file.

Any help to guide me what's happening in here is really appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s usually unnecessary to push local git repo to a local bare repo unless you want to treat the local bare repo as your remote git server.

If you want to hosted the remote repo into 3rd-party (like github, bitbucket VSTS git repo etc), you can push to the remote repo directly:

```
# After migrate svn repo to local git repo by git svn clone command
cd reponame
git remote add origin <remote repo URL>
git push origin --all
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please also guide on this: we have one old code (project) in svn branch rather  than trunk. How to do git clone on that?

Comment: You just need to specify the subdir where the code located, such as `git svn clone <url> --trunk=/relative/path/to/the/subdir`.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways of converting a svn repo to git. 
To name a few, Please refer to below documentation:

Official: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git
Bit bucket: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview

All of them refer to the same process but I found these documentations are pretty well written.